# Can we use string values as output Range in interpolate of animated value in react native?

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated

I can use numbers, boolean values and degrees as strings(i.e '0deg') but I cannot use normal strings values as output Range in interpolate of animated value in react native.As we can see using degrees as strings but why can't we use normal strings as outputRange?